# Using Two tables for retrieveing data

Tags: java, sql

I have two tables (1) REG (2) REG_TEMP

```
REG Columns: REGDNO, NAME
REG_TEMP Columns: DATECOL
```

In REG table I store the the values 0 & 1 to column (i.e Date I select in the program) which I alter in the program, i.e, The date I select will be inserted into REG_TEMP and the same date is altered to become new column for my table REG 
Example: If I take Dec_12_2013 as my date 
                 REG Table becomes REGDNO, NAME, DEC_12_2013(New Column) and the date Dec_12_2013 will become a record in the REG_TEMP table.

Now the problem I encountered is "to display the records of the table REG according to sorted order of the DATECOL in REG_TEMP",

```
REG_TEMP: 

DATECOL
----------
Dec_12_2013
Dec_5_2013
Dec_20_2013
```

Whenever I insert the record REG_TEMP table looks like this and my REG table will have columns like

```
REG
-----------
REGDNO
NAME
Dec_12_2013
Dec_5_2013
Dec_20_2013
```

where the columns are not sorted.

I am not able to sort out the proper SQL statement that gives me the table as

```
REGDNO, NAME, Dec_5_2013, Dec_12_2013, Dec_20_2013
```

with the appropriate records of every column.

That is I need the SQL statement or JAVA code that sorts the dates in the DATECOL of REG_TEMP and retrieve the record in the table REG according to the sorted column name.

Any one please help me out how it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

You're going about this the wrong way.  It's not normal to go round adding new columns to tables, depending on what your data is.

What you actually need is a third table, which stores the values for each combination of REGDNO (which I'm guessing is the primary key of REG) and DATECOL.  So you'll have

```
REG: REGDNO, NAME
REGDATA: REGDNO, DATECOL, VALUE
```

You can then join these two on REGDNO to get the data that you want.